# What is the standard output buffer called?

Tags: c++

When I write a filebuf, everything is ok.
I'd like to know what is called a buffer for standard output.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
  filebuf m;
  m.open("/home/patryk/untitled6/text.txt", ios::out);
  ostream out(&m);
  out<<"to ja";
}
```

I don't want use e.g cout.rdbuf.
Only as above

The name of the output stream

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{

  ostream out(cout.rdbuf());
  out<<"to ja";
}
```

Comment: `std::cout`? Or did I misunderstand something...?

Comment: Have you tried `std::cout<<"to ja";`?

Comment: no I don't want to use cout

Comment: I'd like own cout as if.

Comment: @PatrykWer what you are asking for makes no sense. Please clarify what your actual goal is

Comment: The fact that it isn't nameable should be a very strong hint that you shouldn't be trying to use it.

Comment: Guys, instead of repeatedly saying that it "makes no sense", and suggesting approaches that the OP has already rejected, maybe try politely asking for clarification.

Comment: What *specific* feature of `std::cout` is there that you *don't want*? All you have said is that you want somethink "as if `cout`", which naturally points to just using it.

Comment: I have no idea what is unclear about this question. It even contains code examples illustrating exactly what it means. So I am voting to reopen.

Comment: Hello, Patryk. Please tell me *why* you want to know this. If I knew what your end goal was, I'd be able to help you much easier and with a clearer answer.

Answer (score 2):

It is an implementation defined type derived from `std::streambuf` Here is [what a popular C++ reference says](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/cout):

> The global objects std::cout and std::wcout control output to a stream buffer of implementation-defined type (derived from std::streambuf), associated with the standard C output stream stdout.

This means you can only realistically access the instance currently inside `std::cout`using `std::cout.rdbuf()` - unless your compiler vendor provides non-standard access to its relevant internals.

For example, GCC provides [`stdio_filebuf`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.8.5/libstdc++/api/a01237_source.html), an instance of which could be "wrapped around" the standard output file descriptor.

Comment: *"an implementation defined type"* In other words, there is no way around `std::cout.rdbuf()` other than writing a custom streambuf.

Comment: @SergeyA Well I suppose years of referring to `C`, `POSIX C` & `Linux C`  library reference documentation as the "manual" as they are referred to on `POSIX` systems (man pages) has colored my terminology somewhat. But I am more than happy with the term "reference" as edited by Lightness. In future I will try to remember to RTFR instead of RTFM. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

In both examples, there is no need to use `std::ostream` the way you are.

In the first example, use `std::ofstream` instead of `std::filebuf`:

```
ofstream out("/home/patryk/untitled6/text.txt");
out << "to ja";
```

In the second example, `std::cout` is already a `std::ostream` so just write to it directly:

```
cout << "to ja";
```

In both cases, this abstracts away how the actual buffers are implemented. Just focus on the higher level stream interface by itself.  The buffers used are just implementation details.

Comment: I don't want to use cout

Comment: In constructor ostream I want to add stream for standard stream

Comment: @PatrykWer why? You are not making yourself clear at all. What are you really trying to accomplish? There is no *standard* class that represents the stdout buffer, like there is a *standard* class to represent a file. The default buffer used by `std::cout` is an internal detail of the library implementation on each platform.

Comment: cout is created object I'd like to create own object of ostream class

Comment: There is no standard class to represent `std::cout` buffer, the same way there is no standard class to represent `std::cout` itself. This question makes 0 sense.

Comment: @SergeyA isn't `std::cout` an instance of *exactly* `std::ostream`, having been constructed with an implementation defined `rdbuf`?

Comment: @SergeyA *"There is no standard class"* That's the answer. But if the answer is "it's impossible", it doesn't mean that the question makes no sense.

Comment: @Caleth this is true! I was under impression that the stream is also implementation defined, but I was wrong. Thx for correcting me